# What does the 'L' in front a string mean in C++?

Tags: c++

```
this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
```

Although it seems to work without the `L`, what is the purpose of the prefix? The way it is used doesn't even make sense to a hardcore C programmer.

Comment: You are not using C++.  It is optional in a C++/CLI program if the string literal only contains ASCII characters.  The compiler automatically converts it to a utf-16 encoded string that's interned either way.

Comment: @Hans: _"You are not using C++"_ How do you know?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `textBox1` is a typical .NET name for a TextBox that was dragged and dropped onto a Form.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

It's a `wchar_t` literal, for extended character set. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) has a little discussion on this topic, and c++ examples.

Comment: worth mentioning: this recent (2020) ms discussion on c++ string and character literals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp

Answer (score 137):

'L' means `wchar_t`, which, as opposed to a normal character, requires 16-bits of storage rather than 8-bits. Here's an example:

```
"A"    = 41
"ABC"  = 41 42 43
L"A"   = 00 41
L"ABC" = 00 41 00 42 00 43
```

A `wchar_t` is twice big as a simple char. In daily use you don't need to use wchar_t, but if you are using windows.h you are going to need it.

Comment: note: it's not necessarily 16 bit. It's OS specific.

Comment: I think that in linux wchar_t is 32 bits

Comment: "In daily use you Don't need to use wchar_t" is arbitrary jugement. As a non native English speaker, I can say that I must use it all the time...

Answer (score 22):

It means the text is stored as `wchar_t` characters rather than plain old `char` characters.

(I originally said it meant unicode. I was wrong about that. But it can be used for unicode.)

Answer (score 21):

It means that it is a wide character, `wchar_t`.

Similar to `1L` being a long value.

Answer (score 17):

It means it's an array of wide characters (`wchar_t`) instead of narrow characters (`char`).

It's a just a string of a different kind of character, **not necessarily a Unicode string**.

Answer (score 12):

L is a prefix used for wide strings. Each character uses several bytes (depending on the size of `wchar_t`). The encoding used is independent from this prefix. I mean it must not be necessarily UTF-16 unlike stated in other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the usage:
By adding L before the char you can return Unicode characters as char32_t type:

```
          char32_t utfRepresentation()
      {
                if (m_is_white)
                {
                          return L'♔';
                }

                return L'♚';

      };
```