# How shall this be interpreted?

Tags: c++

This is the C++ code:

```
s.connect(L"TelldusClient");
```

I haven't seen this syntax before. I cannot find where L comes from and what it is. The header file gives:

```
void connect(const std::wstring &server);
```

So it seems like it is some sort of concatenation?

Comment: L"x" is the compilers way for you to specify a Unicode string.  MSVC also has a macro _T("x") which does either Unicode or ASCII depending on your project settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384118/what-does-the-l-in-front-a-string-mean-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "wide character string" in C language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287213/what-is-a-wide-character-string-in-c-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` means the string should be interpreted as a wide string (Unicode).

As you can see, the function accepts `wstring` rather than a regular string, so the `L` is needed before the string.

In Windows, if you include tchar.h, you could also use `_T("SomeString")`, and this will be interpreted as `"SomeString"` if the code is compiled for ANSI, or `L"SomeString"` if it's compiled for Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

`L` means that this string should be coded in Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This is wide string literal. For more details look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal