# Trying to start a server on my newly Rails application on a path with diacritics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, path

I am a newbie at Ruby on Rails and I just follow the *Getting Started* official documentation in order to start a new Rails application.

While I am trying to run the server I am getting a **LoadError** which I know little off, i.e.:

```
PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\John Snow\Projects\Tractări Auto Flex\flex-site\bin> rails server
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- C:/Users/john/Desktop/John Snow/Projects/Tract?ri Auto Flex/flex-site/config/boot (LoadError)
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

My guessing is that it has to do with the path that contains diacritics since I can easily notice that **ă** in the path is not recognized by rails and gets formatted as an **?** or maybe I am wrong and it is something else I am missing.

Any suggestions on how I can circumvent this error are much appreciated.

I am using **Ruby 3.0.3p157** and **Rails 6.1.4.1**.

Comment: Well, put the project  in another path. Ideally the path should be simple without spaces or special chars. Ex:  c:/proiecte/tractari_auto/. See if it works.

Comment: @razvans Well, thank you, it does get past that error using a much simpler path. But now I wonder, is it Rails not working at all with paths with spaces or special characters, or is there anything that could be done to work on the initial path I was using? ... Maybe this is a question for another topic I would guess, idk.

Comment: I lot of years ago I started Rails on Windows, it was Rails 2.3 and I had issues with paths with spaces. That's how I know it. Since then I use simple paths everywhere. Didn't put much thought into why it does not work, proabably it's a windows thing.

Comment: For references, there is an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29087) closed about this, but there was no solution involved. Also, the same behavior was reported on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456278/7698694).

Comment: Similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079788/special-characters-in-file-paths-on-windows-c

Answer (score 0):

In the `bin/rails` file, there is require_relative for loading a boot file for the initialize app.

Try to run the `rails server` command in the `C:\Users\john\Desktop\John Snow\Projects\Tractări Auto Flex\flex-site` path, not inside the `bin` directory

If that doesn't work, check if the `boot.rb` file is in the `config` folder.

Comment: Ok, tried to run the command in the specified path, did not work, got the same error. Also, I confirm that `boot.rb` is there. Thanks for the suggestions.