# Printing ASCII code in C++ (Visual Studio not recognizing encoding)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding, ascii

I'm trying to make a xy program which prints ASCII art in the console with characters such as `⣿`, when running the program just prints question marks (?). I understand that it's either because of me using the wrong encoding or Microsoft Visual Studio not having the dictionary of these ASCII characters.

If you have any idea on how to either change encoding or fix the issue, it would be much appreciated.

[image: What I have wrote]
[image: what vs recognizes it as]

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? What is the code page of your console? What code are you using to write? How do you write your characters in the code? Those informations are essential to know why your output does not match your expectation. **Do you really expect to get help when you don't even make the effort to show your code?**

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- Try to change the source file encoding to `UTF-8 without signature`
  or `UTF-8 with signature`.
- Try to use `wchar_t` literal, i.e. `std::wcout << L"Your String";`.

Learn more:

- [how to change source file encoding in csharp project (visual studio / msbuild machine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840065/13433323) (Also applies to C++)
- [What does the 'L' in front a string mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384118/13433323)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a problem with your code but rather a problem with the console that shows your output. It does not show unicode character correctly. In order for it to show these characters correctly it need to recognize unicode and use a font that actually have those characters. To verify this, simple open a cmd window and copy/paste the character into it and see what heppens.